# Loop through checkboxlist and send email messages based on selection(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net

CheckBoxList selections(more than one allowed). I am trying to find a way to loop through all the selections.  If an item is checked it sends and email to a specific recipient. There can be more than one item selected.  How do i set this up?  Below is what i did and works fine for just item selected, but if i select more than 1 item it doesnt work.  I have only been doing ASP/C# for about 4 months.  Appreciate the help.

**ASP.net**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
<asp:ListItem >Conceptual Object Model</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListIteM >Application Communication Diagram</asp:ListIteM>
<asp:ListItem >Application / Functionality Matrix</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >Application and User Location Model</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >Data Model</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >Role/Application Matrix</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >Process Model / Activity Diagrams</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >One Boeing Capability Map (OBCM)</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >Other (list architecture models below)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

---

**C#**

```
if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue == "Data Model")
{
    // Session["sess_GRPInbox"] = "email1.com";
    Session["sess_2ndEmailperson"] = "email2.com";
}
else
{
    Session["sess_2ndEmailperson"] = "";
}

if (CheckBoxList2.SelectedValue == "No")
{
    Session["sess_3rdEmailperson"] = "email3.com";
}
else
{
    Session["sess_3rdEmailperson"] = "";
}

Session["sess_GrpInbox"] = "email1.com";

Response.Redirect("EmailPage.aspx");
```

---

**Emailer aspx.cs page**

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(Session["sess_GRPInbox"].ToString());
// MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email1.com");
// MailAddress to = new MailAddress(txtOriginatorEmail.Text.Trim());
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("email1.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

// 2nd Email Recipient:
string str_sess_2ndEmailperson = Session["sess_2ndEmailperson"].ToString();

if (str_sess_2ndEmailperson == "") 
{ 
}
else
{
     message.To.Add(Session["sess_2ndEmailperson"].ToString());
}

// string str_sess_3rdEmailperson = Session["sess_3rdEmailperson"].ToString();
// if (str_sess_3rdEmailperson == "")
// {
// }
// else
// {
//     message.To.Add(Session["sess_3rdEmailperson"].ToString());
// }


message.Subject = "Issue Management Submittal Confirmation";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;

String strBody = @"A new proposed issue has been submitted.<br />Click here to view the issue:<br />";

message.Body = strBody;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your check box list something like:

```
 foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
 {
      if(item.Checked)
      {
           sendEmail(item.Value); //assuming your val is the email address
      }
 }
```

Then in your email routine you pass the email address as a paramter

```
 private void sendEmail(string emailAddress)
 {
      //call your email routine here


 }
```